# Simple Countability Problem

Tags: combinatorics

Count the number of strings of length 8 over A = {a, b, c, d} that begins with either a or c and have at least one b.

My attempt:

4^8 total possibilities.  a or c will occupy the first part, so it's (4^8)/2 = 32768 that start with a or c.

There are 7 remaining slots for the "at least one b" criteria:
-xxxxxxx
So, C(7,1)+C(7,2)+C(7,3)+C(7,4)+C(7,5)+C(7,7) = 127

Is the answer 32768+127? Here is where I get stuck!

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to count the total number that begin with a or c, as you did, and **subtract** the number of "bad" strings, the ones that have no b.

These bad strings are easy to count, using the same kind of reasoning as the one you used to get $\frac{4^8}{2}$ for the total number of strings that begin with a or c.

I would count in the following marginally different way:

Total, without worrying about whether or not there is a b: There are $2$ choices for the first place, and then $4$ choices for each of the remaining places, for a total of $2\cdot 4^7$.

Bad strings, start with a or c, but have no b. There are $2$ choices for the first position, and $3$ choices for each of the others, total $2\cdot 3^7$.

So the number of "good" strings is $2\cdot 4^7-1\cdot 3^7$.

Comment: I know the total number of strings for the second part is 4^7

Comment: I have written out a complete solution.

Comment: I see it now.  Thank you! = )

Comment: You are welcome. We used a simple version of Inclusion/Exclusion, count them "all" and throw away the bad ones.